# How to fix height of subreport in master report?

Tags: jasper-reports

I currently have a subreport within a master report.  The Master report has to fit on an A4 page and as a result, I need to have a static height for the subreport as well.

The subreport which is in the "Title" band, takes in a list of text and writes them line by line.  The text fields within this subreport have the flag: "stretch on overflow"  Therefore, the height of the subreport is dynamic depending on the number of items in the list and whether the text fields were stretched or not.

The data passed into the subreport does not all need to be displayed.  I simply want to display as much data as will fit and truncate or ignore the rest of the data.

Is there any way to have a fixed height for the subreport?  I don't want it to overflow OR to show up on another page.  I just want it to truncate or ignore the rest of the data within the list.

Answer (score 0):

yes, if you set the stretch type to 'No Stretch' as an attribute for your subreport in the master report. Additionally, you can set your textfields *isStretchWithOverflow* to **false**.

Further information: [JasperReports - Stretch Sample](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/stretch/)